# adding network flag --network-plugin=cni to kubelet

Tags: kubernetes

Beginners question sorry for asking i searched on google how i need to add flags to my already running kubelet i have to add the flags 
--network-plugin=cni --network-plugin-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin

When i navigate to the /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file these flags are already added to the env kubelet network args.

Is kubelet already configured with these flags or do i need to add those flag in an other file ?

PS: The reason i need to add those flags is a solution (maybe a solution i'am still debugging ) for my kubernetes problem: [kubernetes pods stuck at containercreating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113253/kubernetes-pods-stuck-at-containercreating)

Answer (score 2):

The kubelet by default comes with the flags you mentioned. If you have access to the nodes running this cluster, you can check the running kubelet process to check whether it started using the flags mentioned above using

```
ps -ef | grep kubelet
```

You would have an output similar to this

```
root     11841     1  3 Mar07 ?        05:46:46 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cadvisor-port=0 --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --cloud-provider=openstack --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud-config --rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki
```

If you still want to change config , edit /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file and restart kubelet for the changes to take into effect

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```